# creating table via document.onload won't function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm wondering as to why the following ceases to function, for whatever peculiar reason:

```
document.onload=function() {
 table = document.createElement("table");
 table.setAttribute("border", "1");
 document.body.appendChild(table);
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

You all have my sincere thanks for offering your solutions! :D

Comment: Under what conditions does it "cease to function?" What do you mean by "cease to function?" The callback is never executed? And why aren't you using CSS to style the table?

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you don't mean `window.onload`?

```
window.onload=function() {
 table = document.createElement("table");
 table.setAttribute("border", "1");
 document.body.appendChild(table);
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rzfuG/

**EDIT**

With some extra html created for demonstration purposes:

```
window.onload=function() {
 table = document.createElement("table");
 table.setAttribute("border", "1");
 document.body.appendChild(table);
 tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
 tr = document.createElement('tr');
 td = document.createElement('td');
 td.innerHTML = "test";
 table.appendChild(tbody);
 tbody.appendChild(tr);
 tr.appendChild(td);
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rzfuG/1/

**EDIT 2**

Now, if you're thinking of the body tag's onload attribute, you could do:

```
<body onload="my_onload();"></body>

function my_onload() {
 table = document.createElement("table");
 table.setAttribute("border", "1");
 document.body.appendChild(table);
 tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
 tr = document.createElement('tr');
 td = document.createElement('td');
 td.innerHTML = "test";
 table.appendChild(tbody);
 tbody.appendChild(tr);
 tr.appendChild(td);
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rzfuG/2/

Note, however, this is the same as `window.onload`. In fact, you can't do both `window.onload=...` and `<body onload="...`, since the body onload will override the JS and only one will run.

See http://jsfiddle.net/rzfuG/3/

Comment: Thanks for the response! I didn't use window.onload since document.body hasn't loaded yet (and needed to append the table to the body, and hence, had thusly used document.onload instead -- document.body (or document.documentElement.childNodes[1]) doesn't work either (:/))

Ah, it works now with the window.onload, thanks! :D

Comment: @user784446 - Did you see the jsfiddle demos?

Comment: @user784446 - Also, if you want to run something on DOM ready, use jQuery's `.ready()` method, which is cross-browser supported. `document.onload` is not cross-browser supported, AFAIK.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I'll be using jQuery soon, but want to understand JS first.

Comment: @user784446 - I'm supposing I'm not understanding your problem. The code examples above work - what is different in your particular implementation?

Comment: I thought it wasn't working -- Chrome usually updates the source of the page if it's been modified during runtime.

Comment: @user784446 - Note, I was thinking the JS would override the body tag onload, but it's actually the other way around.

Comment: @Jared: [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener#Older_way_to_register_event_listeners) is cross-browser supported. One should probably use addEventListener, though …

Comment: @Kay - I said `document.onload`, not `window.onload`.

Comment: @Jared: "… but it's actually the other way around." -- I would'nt rely on that ;)

Comment: @Kay - True. But I did not say anything about `window.onload` not being cross-browser. ;)